# Wildfly 10 Start, Stop Scripts for Standalone

Tags: linux, jboss, wildfly-10

I am unable to stop the wildfly 10 standalone server in Linux Env. And using the following commands:

```
start: ./standalone.sh (working fine)
stop: ./jboss-cli.sh -c --command=:shutdown  (Unable to stop the server)
```

Note: Stop command is working fine in windows env by executing the command:

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --command=:shutdown(timeout=60)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `timeout` parameter which you know works on windows?

Comment: Yes, but it shows an error as "unexpected character '(' " after adding timeout value. I tried to escape with "<" symbol but still issue exists.

Comment: $ ./jboss-cli.sh -c --command=:shutdown<(timeout=10)
    'shutdown/dev/fd/63' is not a valid operation name.

Answer (score 2):

How about using  **kill** linux command :

On Cent OS this works :

```
ps aux | grep wildfly | grep -v grep| awk '{print $2} | xargs kill
```

Comment: Thanks @Jitsonfire. But any suggestions to stop server from Wildfly provided scripts?

Answer (score 1):

what error/s you are getting while shutting down server ? Try with :

> jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=127.0.0.1:9999 --command=":shutdown()" --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD